# How is the averaging of this stochastic process determined?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, random, average

I am reading a physics paper dealing with a random fluctuation $R(t)$ satisfying:

1. $\langle R(t)\rangle = 0$.
2. $\langle R(t) R(t')\rangle = \delta(t - t')$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta function

The paper says:

> $R(t)$ is not a well-behaved function. Instead of its instantaneous value, which is not well-defined, one needs to take its average over the interval $\delta t$, which depends on $\delta t$ and is $r/\sqrt{\delta t}$, where $r$ is a random number with $\langle r \rangle = 0$ and $\langle r^2\rangle = 1$.

My Question is: How was this average determined?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: It's helpful to link to the original paper. I'm guessing R(t) appears on the right hand side of a differential equation. In that case the integral of this "function" is well defined

Comment: This is the paper, on page 4: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5081.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In this paper, $R(t)$ is a gaussian white noise which is formally the derivative of a [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process). When integrated over time $\delta t$, it becomes a normally distributed random variable with mean zero and standard deviation $\sqrt{\delta t}$. So its average, (its integral over $\delta t$) would be $1/\sqrt{\delta t}$ times a normalized random variable that is called $r$ here.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is all making sense now

Comment: You're very welcome. You can accept the answer if it has answered your question.